# Change sidebar navigation based on current post

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, categories

I have a category navigation in the wordpress sidebar which contains two main categories A and B. In these categories there are subcategories like A1, A2, ...

For example when main category A is selected...

```
|   A   |   B   |
|       --------|
| - A1          |
| - A2          |
| - A3          |
```

... and when B is selected:

```
|   A   |   B   |
|--------       |
| - B1          |
| - B2          |
| - B3          |
```

The problem is, that A is default (when you first visit the blog) but when a user selects an article from category B1 the postback is sent to the server and the article is displayed. But then A is selected again.

My idea was to check which post is currently displayed and switch the navigation based on this. But how can I find out which article is currently displayed when the code is in the `sidebar.php` and not in the wordpress loop?

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this plugin: http://www.screenshine.net/blog/1474_wordpress-plugin-show-active-category
and then using jQuery to search for the item with the highlighted class, searched the parent div of it, checked if it's A or B and based upon what it is I show A and hide B or show B and hide A.

Answer (score 0):

2 Ideas for how you could do it.

First. You could use 2 plugins:
xwidgets which lets you select sidebar content on a per-page and per-post basis and combine it with WP Category Post List widget.
Here are the links:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xwidgets/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-posts-list/

These are 2 very powerful plugins.

So you could select what you wanted displayed each time you posted something.

OR:

Second. You could insert a some custom fields into your sidebar.php telling controlling which content to display which you would select via the custom field setup in your posts page.

if you have never used custom fields here is a great intro tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/quick-tip-a-4-minute-crash-course-in-wordpress-custom-fields/

and you may want to use some version of this code in your sidebar:

```
<?php // conditional sidebar display
if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "aContent", true)) {
include('a_content.php'); 
} ?>
```

With this example, a_content.php could be a widgetized php file you include with your templates.

You could double this with b_content.php as the other choice.

Hope this helps.
I can explain further if you need.

Thank you,
Ian